# Angular 5 / Material 2 - Wrong value in field after option is selected

Tags: mongodb, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I'm facing a problem with my [Angular Material 2 Autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) fields.

This is my setup:

**hardwareCreate.component.ts**

```
myControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
availableFirmware = [];
filteredFirmware: Observable<any[]>;
selectedFirmware = null;
selectedFirmwareName = '';



this.availableFirmware = [];

    this.terminalService.getFirmware().subscribe(firmware => {
      this.availableFirmware = firmware.firmware;
    });
    this.filteredFirmware = this.myControl.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(val => this.filterFirmware(val))
    );

filterFirmware(val: any): any[] {
    return this.availableFirmware.filter(firmware => {
      return firmware.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
  }
```

**hardwareCreate.component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Firmware auswählen" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto1" [(ngModel)]="selectedFirmwareName">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let firmware of filteredFirmware | async" [value]="firmware._id">
                    {{ firmware.name }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

So my problem now is, that when I type I get the firmware.name attribute which is correct and looks like this:
[image]

But when I now select a firmware, the `value` changes to the `_id` of  `firmware`.
[image]

So I could change `[value]="firmware._id"` to `[value]="firmware.name"` but I need the ID for my mongodb ->

```
firmware: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Firmware'
    },
```

**Question:**
How can I change the display value to the name, but still get the Id for my Database when the user selects a specific firmware?

---

The solution now is a combination of both of vsoni and JEYs answers. The problem at the end was, that `val` was an object. By converting it to a string, anything works like a charme! 
Thanks to both of you!

Comment: try  value="{{firmware._id}}" instead of  [value]="firmware._id"

Comment: doesn't work - same result, it shows the `firmware._id`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `displayWith` function.

Your **component.html** would become

```
<div class="form-group">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Firmware auswählen" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto1">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let firmware of filteredFirmware | async" [value]="firmware" (onSelectionChange)="getXXX(firmware)>
                {{ firmware.name }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Then define following display function in you **component.ts**

```
displayFn(firmware: any): string {
  return firmware? firmware.name : firmware;
}
```

You can access firmware id in `getXXX(firmware)` function which you define in your **component.ts**. This function will be called on selection change.

```
getXXX(firmware) {
   this.selectedFirmware = firmware;
   // here you can get id 
  // firmware._id
}
```

and filter function

```
filterFirmware(val: any): any[] {
    let name = val.name ? val.name : val;
    return this.availableFirmware.filter(firmware => {
      return firmware.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but after i changed anything, there is nothing displayed inside the field anymore. Do you have any ideas what can cause this?

Comment: Just check whether the displayFn() is being called? You can debug and see what you are getting in firmware object in displayFn(). Whether firmware object contains name property?

Comment: yes `displayFirmware()` is called and after playing around i found out, that `firmware` of `displayFirmware(firmware: any): string {` only contains the `id` as a string and not the name - so how do i get the full `firmware` object over there? Sorry, i'm a bit confused about angular / typescript right now and hope, that my comment helps you to understand what i mean.

Comment: you need to change [value]="firmware._id" to [value]="firmware" as I had put in my answer.

Comment: great, seems to work! Another problem just appeared: It gets in conflict with my val.toLowerCase() from my function: `filterFirmware(val: any): any[] {
    return this.availableFirmware.filter(firmware => {
      return firmware.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
  }`

It says: val.toLowerCase() is not a function

Man thanks a lot for your invested time, i realy appreciate it!

Comment: i made a video - hope this is clear enough
http://recordit.co/CnuwT4I3ee

Comment: @Sithys - try with `map(val => val ? this.filterFirmware(val) : this.availableFirmware.slice())`  in place of  `map(val => this.filterFirmware(val))`

Comment: Same error - the error occurs after selecting a firmware. I don't know, from which function that comes. Console says line 29 in my html but that would be `<input type="text" placeholder="Firmware auswählen" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto1" [(ngModel)]="selectedFirmwareName">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163942/discussion-between-vsoni-and-sithys).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [displayWith](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values) attribute like:

In your component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import {startWith} from 'rxjs/operators/startWith';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  
  myControl = new FormControl();
  availableFirmware = [{name: 'Firmware 1', id: 1}, {name: 'Firmware 2', id: 2}, {name: 'Firmware 3', id: 3}];
  selected = null;
  filteredFirmware: Observable<any>;
  subcribtion: Subscription;

  displayFirmware(firmware?: any) {
    return firmware ? firmware.name : undefined;
  }

  filterFirmware(val: any): any[] {
    return this.availableFirmware.filter(firmware => {
      // when no selection occured value is a string
      // but once a firmware is selected value is an object
      let name = val.name ? val.name : val;
      return firmware.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subcribtion = this.myControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => this.selected = value);
    this.filteredFirmware = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(val => this.filterFirmware(val))
    );

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subcribtion.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

In the template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Firmware auswählen" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto1">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFirmware">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let firmware of filteredFirmware | async" [value]="firmware">
                {{ firmware.name }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>

<p>
  {{selected | json}}
</p>
```

In this solution the value is the whole firmware object so you can retrieve anything from it.

You can find a running example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptg4i1

Comment: Same here like at the answer above: Thanks for your answer but after i changed anything, there is nothing displayed inside the field anymore. Do you have any ideas what can cause this?

Comment: I updated my answer with the code you provided. And a running example of this code.